# Как передать ссылку из дочернего компонента в родительский?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
Parent.tsx
const Parent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
**Здесь нужно получить ссылку для работы с ней

    return (
    <Child/>
    )
}

Child.tsx
}
const Child: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

    const ref = React.createRef()
    return (
    <div ref={ref.current}>
    )

}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: передайте функцию просто, которая изменяет стейт родителя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любые данные, которые нужно передать "вверх" - передаются путем передачи их в функцию, которая переданна из родительского компонента.

Parent.tsx

```
    const Parent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
        const [childRef, setChildRef] = useState(null); 
    
        return (
           <Child setRef={setChildRef} />
        )
    }
    
    Child.tsx
    const Child: React.FunctionComponent = ({ setRef }) => {
        const ref = React.createRef()

        useEffect(() => {
           setRef(ref);
        }, [ref]);

        return (
           <div ref={ref.current}>
        )
    
    }
```